# Testing convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n\ \frac{4^{n}(n!)^{2}}{(2n)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me to prove whether this series is convergent or divergent:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^n\ \frac{4^{n}(n!)^{2}}{(2n)!}$$

I tried using the ratio test, but the limit of the ratio in this case is equal to 1 which is inconclusive in this case. Any hints please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Hint: Use the alternating series convergence test.</strike>

The work you already did is not wasted: $$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{4(n+1)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}=\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}>1$$

Hence the terms do not approach 0 in absolute value, and by the $n^\textrm{th}$ term test, the series diverges.

Answer (score 5):

I understand why the series was demonstrated to diverge.  But please allow me to be devil's advocate here and demonstrate that the sum may be assigned a finite value in the sense of an analytic continuation.

I refer to the result I derived yesterday in connection with [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420732/trying-to-prove-that-sum-j-2-infty-prod-k-1j-frac2-kjk-1-pi/420886#420886):

$$\frac{x \, \arcsin{x}}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{1-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2 n}}{\displaystyle \binom{2 n}{n}} x^{2 n}$$

Then making the substitution $x \mapsto i x$ I get

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{2^{2 n}}{\displaystyle \binom{2 n}{n}} x^{2 n}  = \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{x \, \log{(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}$$

The radius of convergence of this series is in fact $1$.  Well, sort of.  Obviously, at $x=1$, the series in fact diverges as demonstrated above.  But the limit of the sum as $x \to 1^-$ exists and is equal to

$$\frac12 \left (1-\frac{\log{(1+\sqrt{2})}}{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \approx 0.188387$$

Comment: Happy 30k, btw.

Comment: @julien: thanks!  We've come a long way, haven't we?  Anyway, I decided against having even one heart-attack burger to celebrate, never mind three, as I would be at risk of not seeing 40k.

Comment: Right. We need you to keep rolling and in good shape!

Comment: @julien: Shucks, that's nice.  Anyway, my kids got me a hat with a turtle on it.  I thought for a minute it was for reaching 30k, but then it occurred to me that today is Father's Day.

Comment: (+1) I had the same devil idea but refrained :-) Thanks for the neat realization and Felicitations for your 30k!

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: many thanks.  Why did you refrain?  This is a very nifty aspect of this particular sum and I was surprised that nobody addressed it.  Best of all, in what looks like a crazy coincidence, I had just (almost) derived a closed-form expression for the series the day before, so I couldn't resist. Anyway, keep up the great work.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You may use Stirling or more quickly this equivalence for [central binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties) as $n\to \infty$ :
$$\binom{2n}{n}\sim \frac {4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Answer (score 3):

By Stirling's approximation $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$, so

$$\frac{4^{n}(n!)^{2}}{(2n)!}\sim \frac{2\pi n 4^{n} (n/e)^{2n}}{\sqrt{4\pi n}(2n/e)^{2n}} =\sqrt{\pi n}.$$ Thus, the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You cannot use the alternating series test. Since

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{4^n n!^2}{(2n)!} \neq 0. $$ You can use the identity

$$ (2n)!=\Gamma(2n+1)={\frac {n  {4}^{n}\Gamma  \left( n \right) \Gamma 
 \left( \frac{1}{2}+n \right) }{\sqrt {\pi }}},$$

or [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to see this.

Comment: No... $$\frac{4^n n!^2}{(2n)!} \sim \sqrt{\pi n}.$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas: What's no?

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{4^n n!^2}{(2n)!} \neq 0.$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Are you sure?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: I was considering the wrong one $$ \frac{4^n n!}{(2n)!}. $$. Thanks

Comment: No problem.  And you're right, if the square wasn't there it'd be a different story.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: See the correction

Comment: @Downvoter: There was a mistake and it was corrected. So, what is the down vote for? While others made corrections too!!