# Evaluate this power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

Evaluate the sum

$$x+\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}x^5+\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{6}{7}x^7+\dots$$

Totally no idea. I think this series may related to the $\sin x$ series because of those missing even powers. Another way of writing this series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!}x^{2k+1}.$$

Comment: Those missing even powers simply mean that your function is an odd function; that is, $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77869/13854), I mention this identity, which can be proven by repeated integration by parts:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2k+1}(x)\;\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2k}{2k+1}\frac{2k-2}{2k-1}\cdots\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{4^k}{\binom{2k}{k}}\tag{1}
$$
Your sum can be rewritten as
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)}\frac{4^k}{\binom{2k}{k}}x^{2k+1}\tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sin^{2k+1}(t)x^{2k+1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\sin(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}{1-x^2\sin^2(t)}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{-\,\mathrm{d}x\cos(t)}{1-x^2+x^2\cos^2(t)}\\
&=-\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left.\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x\cos(t)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\right]_0^{\pi/2}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{\sin^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Radius of Convergence**

This doesn't appear to be part of the question, but since some other answers have touched on it, I might as well add something regarding it.

A corollary of [Cauchy's Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) is that the radius of convergence of a complex analytic function is the distance from the center of the power series expansion to the nearest singularity. The nearest singularity of $f(z)$ to $z=0$ is $z=1$. Thus, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I refer you to [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420732/trying-to-prove-that-sum-j-2-infty-prod-k-1j-frac2-kjk-1-pi/420886#420886).  The function $f(x)$ represented by the sum in question is

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2 n}}{\displaystyle (2 n+1) \binom{2 n}{n}} x^{2 n+1} = \frac{\arcsin{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

You may deduce that the radius of convergence is $1$ from the relation

$$\frac{1}{2^{2 n}} \binom{2 n}{n} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} \quad (n \to \infty)$$

which may be shown as a result of, e.g., Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out $\lim {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$, $a_n={1.2.\dots 2n \over 1.3.5\dots 2n+1}x^{2n+1}$

Comment: That would help you find the radius of convergence. But the sum?

Comment: I think it means to find some $f(x)$ which coincides with this power series within the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
[Note that](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html)
$\ds{\pars{2k}!! = 2^{k}\,\Gamma\pars{k + 1}}$ and
$\ds{\pars{2k + 1}!! = 2^{k + 1}\,{\Gamma\pars{k + 3/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1/2}}}$.
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{2k}!! \over
\pars{2k + 1}!!}\,x^{2k + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\Gamma\pars{k + 1}
\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{k + 3/2}}\,x^{2k + 1}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1}t^{k}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\,\dd t}\,x^{2k + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,x\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over \root{1 - t}}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{x^{2}\,t}^{k}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,x\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over \root{1 - t}}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{x^{2}\,t}^{k}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,x\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over
\root{1 - t}\pars{1 - x^{2}t}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{t\ =\ 1 - \xi^{2}}{=}\,\,\,\,\,&
x\int_{0}^{1}{\dd\xi \over
1 - x^{2}\pars{1 - \xi^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
x\,{1 \over 1 - x^{2}}\,{\root{1 - x^{2}} \over x}\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{x/\root{1 - x^{2}}}\dd\xi \over
\pars{x\xi/\root{1 - x^{2}}}^{2} + 1}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\arctan\pars{x \over \root{1 - x^2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.{\arctan\pars{\tan\pars{\theta}} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}
\,\right\vert_{\,x\ =\ \sin\pars{\theta}} =
\bbx{\arcsin\pars{x} \over \root{1 - x^{2}}} \\ &
\end{align}