# How to evaluate $I=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\log{\sin{(x)}}}{\sin(x)}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form, trigonometric-integrals

Prima facie, this integral seems easy to calculate,but alas, this not's case $$I=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\log{\sin{(x)}}}{\sin(x)}\,dx$$
 The numerical value is I=-1.122690024730644497584272...
 How to evaluate this integral?
By against,I find:
 $$I=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\log{\sin{(x)}}}{\sin(2x)}\,dx=-\frac{\pi^3}{48}$$

Comment: What does 'by against' mean?

Comment: Vote to keep open.

Comment: user 111187, I mean it is possible to calculate $$I=-\frac{\pi^3}{48}$$

Comment: I think maybe a mapping to the first quadrant of the unit circle will work. We can then set this integral equal to the integrals over the line segments $(0,i)$ and $(0,1)$. The resulting integrals seems to be expressible in terms of special values of Dilogartihms. 
The problem is that i'm a little bit too busy to make real toughts about the correct choices of logaritmic branches etc, so i hope someone can get a result from my suggestions

Comment: A really interesting integral by the way :)

Comment: @tired "... this integral seems easy to calculate..." seems too confident if one knows that already $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{xdx}{\sin x}$ is expressed in terms of Catalan's constant.

Comment: @O.L where have i said the integral is "easy to calculate"?
I rather think it's a very difficult integral and just wrote down a possible way to crack this hard nut...

Comment: Or did you mean the statement of the opener of this topic?

Comment: @tired Indeed, I just quoted the OP. I see no reason for it to be simple.

Comment: Ok, then we totally agree :)
Do you think my suggestion could possibly work?

Comment: I really think my approach will work out, but unfortunately i don't have the time to work out a solution until maybe Monday. So please feel free to use my thoughts...I think the solution will consists only of linear combintions of $\frac{c}{d}\zeta(3),\frac{a\pi^u}{b}log[2]$ and $\frac{e\pi^v}{f}$ with $a,b,c,d,ef,u,v$ integer numbers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I want to suggest a partial solution which i call  "partial" because some of the work is done using Mathematica but i hope i can fill this gaps in the next time.

Lets define the complex valued function $f(z)=z\frac{\log(\sin(z))}{(\sin(z))}$. We want to integrate it around a rectangle with vertices $(0,0)$,$(\pi/2,0)$, $(\pi/2,\pi/2+i \infty)$ and $(0,\pi/2+i \infty)$. We also implicitly assume a small indent around $(0,0)$. Now by using Cauchy's integral theorem we can write 
$$
\int_Cf(z)dz=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x \log(\sin(x))}{\sin(x)}dx+ i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{iy \log(\sin(i y))}{\sin(i y)}dy+i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(iy+\pi/2)\log(\sin(iy+\pi/2 ))}{\sin(iy+\pi/2)}dy=0
$$

Were we used the fact the the integral vanishs at the top of the rectangle (This contribution goes as $R^2 e^{-R}$ for big $R$) as well as the contribiution stemming from the small indent around zero (This contribution behaves as $\epsilon \log(\epsilon$) near the origin).

Now using the identities $\sin(iy+\pi/2)=\cosh(y)$ and $\sin(iy)=i\sinh(y)$ This can be rewritten as 
$$
\int_Cf(z)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\log(\sin(x))}{\sin(x)}dx+ i\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y (\log\sinh( y)+i \pi/2)}{\sinh(y)}dy}_{I_1}+i\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(iy+\pi/2)\log(\cosh(y))}{\cosh(y)}dy}_{I_2}=0
$$

Here we choose the standard branch of the logarithm.

Splitting $I_1$ and $I_2 $ we are now down to the four integrals

$$
J_1=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y\log(\sinh(y))}{\sinh(y)}dy\\
J_2=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y}{\sinh(y)}dy\\
J_3=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y\log(\cosh(y))}{\cosh(y)}dy\\
J_4=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(\cosh(y)}{\cosh(y)}dy
$$

Now let's perform a chain of substitutions $r=e^{y}$ and $r^2=q$ in the integrals involving $\cosh$ and $r=e^{-y}$ and $r^2=q$ in the integrals involving $\sinh$
after some tedious algebra we end up with:
$$
J_1= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{1}{4}\log(q)^2-\frac{1}{2}\log(q)\log(1-q)+\frac{1}{2}\log(q)\log(2)}{(1-q)\sqrt{q}}dq\\
J_2=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log(q)}{(1-q)\sqrt{q}}dq\\
J_3=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{2}\log(q)(\log(2)-\frac{1}{2}\log(q)+\log(1+q)}{(1+q)\sqrt{q}}dq\\
J_4=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log(2)-\frac{1}{2}\log(q)+\log(1+q)}{(1+q)\sqrt{q}}dq
$$

The first two integrals can easily solved by using the identity

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^n(1-t)\log^m(t)}{(1-t)^vt^w}dt=\partial^n_{\alpha}\partial^m_{\beta}\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{\alpha-v}t^{\beta-w}dt|_{\alpha=\beta=0}=\partial^n_{\alpha}\partial^m_{\beta}\frac{\Gamma[1 + \beta + v] \Gamma[1 + \alpha + w]}{\Gamma[2 + \alpha + \beta + v + w]}\big|_{\alpha=\beta=0}
$$

Here $\Gamma[z]$ denotes Euler's Gamma function.

Please note that we implicitly assume that this expression exists, which is of course not the case for every choice of parameters.

For the other two integrals i'm not sure how to perform them (I suspect they can somehow be reduced to explicit integral representations of the dilogarithm), but they can be obtained in Mathematica.

We get
$$
J_1=\frac{\pi^2 \log(2)}{8}\\
J_2=\frac{\pi^2}{8}\\
J_3=\frac{1}{96} \left(-2 i \left(-192 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+105 \zeta (3)+4 \log ^3(2)\right)+15 \pi ^3+12 \pi  \log ^2(2)+10 i \pi ^2 \log (2)\right)\\
J_4= \frac{2 \pi \log(2)}{4}
$$

Now merging everything together we obtain 
$$
I=-I_1-I_2=\frac{1}{96} \left(-2 i \left(-192 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+105 \zeta (3)+4 \log ^3(2)\right)+3 \pi ^3+12 \pi  \log ^2(2)+2 i \pi ^2 \log (32)\right)
$$

or 
$$
I\approx-1.12269
$$

as expected from numerical calculations

PS: I would highly appreciate any hint how to perform $J_3$

Appendix: Calculation of $J_4$

I finally found a way to at least calculate $J_4$

Starting from the original definition and using $y=e^q$ and $q=1/x$ one realizes that the integral can be rewritten as

$$
J_4/2=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{-\log(2)}{x^2+1}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{-\log(x)+\log(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}dx
$$

The first one is a standard integral and equal to $-\log(2)\frac{\pi}{2}$ the third one is easily evaluated using a dogbone contour and yields $0$ So it remains to calculate 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{\log(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}
$$

Using the identiy $$\log(1+x^2)=\int_{0}^1 da \frac{x^2}{1+ax^2}$$ 
this is equal to

$$
\int_{0}^1 da \int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)(1+ax^2)} = \int_{0}^1 da\frac{\pi }{2 \left(a+\sqrt{a}\right)}=\pi \log (2)
$$

Plugging everything together yields

$$
J_4=\frac{\pi}{2}\log[2]
$$

as expected.

So only $J_3$ remains...

Comment: *I would highly appreciate any hint how to perform* $J_3$ - [Wouldn't we all ?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918680) ;-$)$

Comment: Good job over there. (+1)

Comment: @tired: Chris's sis points out that using [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/920995) to evaluate $\mathrm{Li}_3\!\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)$, our answers agree.

Comment: Very nice work,appreciate the answer(+1)

Comment: @Ron,Lucian the links are quite intresting. I wasn't aware of all this connections

Comment: Nice solution methodology! +1

Answer (score 5):

The answer is shown to be a fairly simple series and Mathematica identifies that series with a hypergeometric function. I have verified Mathematica's claim and used Mathematica to evaluate the hypergeometric function.

---

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/534857), it is shown that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)}\frac{4^k}{\binom{2k}{k}}x^{2k+1}
=\frac{\sin^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag{1}
$$
Furthermore, integration by parts shows that
$$
\int_0^1x^n\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac1{(n+1)^2}\tag{2}
$$
Substituting $u=\sin(x)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\log(\sin(x))}{\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{\sin^{-1}(u)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\frac{\log(u)}u\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)}\frac{4^k}{\binom{2k}{k}}u^{2k}\log(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)^3}\frac{4^k}{\binom{2k}{k}}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Mathematica identifies $(3)$ with the hypergeometric function
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #A0A0A0]{-{\vphantom{\mathrm{F}}}_4\mathrm{F}_3\left(\color{#C00000}{\tfrac12,\tfrac12},\color{#00A000}{1},\color{#F0A000}{1};\color{#0000FF}{\tfrac32,\tfrac32,\tfrac32};1\right)}\tag{4}
$$
This can easily be verified by looking at the ratios of the terms in $(3)$:
$$
\overbrace{4\vphantom{\frac{()^2}{()}}}^{4^k}\cdot\overbrace{\frac{(k+1)^2}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}}^{1/\binom{2k}{k}}\cdot\overbrace{\frac{(2k+1)^3}{(2k+3)^3}}^{1/(2k+1)^3}
=\frac{\color{#C00000}{(k+\frac12)^2}\color{#00A000}{(k+1)}}{\color{#0000FF}{(k+\frac32)^3}}\cdot1\tag{5}
$$
The orange $1$ cancels the $k!$ in the denominator of the definition of the hypergeometric functions.

Mathematica evaluates $(4)$ as
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #A0A0A0]{-1.12269002473064449758427221442}\tag{6}
$$

Comment: Also good answer(+1)

Answer (score 3):

[The closed form of the integral](http://pastebin.com/ks0WWp8P) 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\log{\sin{(x)}}}{\sin(x)}\,dx.$$

Also note the second integral, that is $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\log{\sin{(x)}}}{\sin(2x)}\,dx$$
can be easily evaluated by combining $2$ integrations by parts (to get again the integral we started with) and beta function.

Comment: Tanks,this result is complex,while the integral is simple.

Answer (score 3):

There is a closed-form of your integral.

$$I = \frac{\pi^3}{32} + \frac{\pi}{8}\ln^2 2 - 4\,\Im\left[\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)\right],$$

where $\operatorname{Li}_3$ is the [trilogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

We could derive it from robjohn's answer, using [Cleo's result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/920995/153012) here.

You could find a [related problem here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1168209/153012).

Comment: Above or below in order depends on how one views the answers: votes, recent, oldest.

Comment: Very well (+1).Thank

Answer (score 2):

By **Weierstrass subs**, the integral boils down to **well-known** integrals

$$2 \log (2) \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} \textrm{d}x+2 \int_0^1 \frac{ \arctan(x)\log (x)}{x} \textrm{d}x-2 \int_0^1 \frac{ \arctan(x)\log (1+x^2)}{x} \textrm{d}x,$$
$$=\frac{\pi^3}{32} + \frac{\pi}{8}\log^2(2) - 4\,\Im\biggr\{\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)\biggr\}.$$

**End of story**

Answer (score 1):

Based on manipulation of real functions after the half-angle substitution, the integral can be transformed to an known polylog integral

\begin{align} \int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\log(\sin{x})}{\sin x}\,dx
=& -4 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1-t)}{1+t^2} dt \\
= & \>4\>\text{Im} \>\text{Li}_3(1+i) -\frac{3\pi^3}{16}
-\frac\pi4\ln^22
\end{align}

Comment: very well(+1).Thank

Answer (score 1):

This solution from my brother, he doesn't use MSE at all, but I think it worths sharing.
$$\begin{array}{l}
 * {\rm\text{Perform integration by parts}}:\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
u = x\\
dv = \frac{{\ln \left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)}}{{\sin \left( {2x} \right)}}
\end{array} \right. \displaystyle\Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
du = dx\\
v = \frac{1}{4}\left( {{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {1 - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) - {\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( { - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) + {{\ln }^2}\left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right) - \ln \left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)\ln \left( {1 + \sin \left( x \right)} \right)} \right)
\end{array} \right.\\
 \displaystyle\Rightarrow I = \left. {\frac{1}{4}x\left( {{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {1 - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) - {\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( { - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) + {{\ln }^2}\left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right) - \ln \left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)\ln \left( {1 + \sin \left( x \right)} \right)} \right)} \right|_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} - \frac{1}{4}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\left( {{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {1 - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) - {\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( { - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) + {{\ln }^2}\left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right) - \ln \left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)\ln \left( {1 + \sin \left( x \right)} \right)} \right)dx} \\
 \displaystyle= \frac{{{\pi ^3}}}{{96}} + \frac{1}{4}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\left( {{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( { - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) - {\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {1 - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) - {{\ln }^2}\left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right) + \ln \left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)\ln \left( {1 + \sin \left( x \right)} \right)} \right)dx} \\
{\rm\text{Utilise dilogarithm identity}}:\displaystyle{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( { - z} \right) - {\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {1 - z} \right) + \frac{1}{2}{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {1 - {z^2}} \right) =  - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{12}} - \ln \left( z \right)\ln \left( {1 + z} \right),{\rm{ let}}:z = \sin \left( x \right)\\
 \displaystyle\Rightarrow {\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( { - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) - {\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {1 - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) + \frac{1}{2}{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {1 - {{\sin }^2}\left( x \right)} \right) =  - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{12}} - \ln \left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)\ln \left( {1 + \sin \left( x \right)} \right)\\
 \displaystyle\Rightarrow {\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( { - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) - {\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {1 - \sin \left( x \right)} \right) =  - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{12}} - \ln \left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)\ln \left( {1 + \sin \left( x \right)} \right) - \frac{1}{2}{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {{{\cos }^2}\left( x \right)} \right)\\
 \displaystyle\Rightarrow I = \frac{{{\pi ^3}}}{{96}} + \frac{1}{4}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\left( { - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{12}} - \ln \left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)\ln \left( {1 + \sin \left( x \right)} \right) - \frac{1}{2}{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {{{\cos }^2}\left( x \right)} \right) - {{\ln }^2}\left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right) + \ln \left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)\ln \left( {1 + \sin \left( x \right)} \right)} \right)dx} \\
 \displaystyle= \frac{{{\pi ^3}}}{{96}} + \frac{1}{4}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\left( { - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{{12}} - \frac{1}{2}{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {{{\cos }^2}\left( x \right)} \right) - {{\ln }^2}\left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)} \right)dx}  \displaystyle= \frac{1}{4}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\left( { - \frac{1}{2}{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {{{\cos }^2}\left( x \right)} \right) - {{\ln }^2}\left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)} \right)dx}  \displaystyle=  - \frac{1}{8}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {{{\cos }^2}\left( x \right)} \right)dx}  - \frac{1}{4}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {{{\ln }^2}\left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)dx} \\
 * \displaystyle J =\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {{{\cos }^2}\left( x \right)} \right)dx}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^2}}}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {{{\cos }^{2n}}\left( x \right)dx = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^2}}}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {{{\sin }^{2n}}\left( x \right)dx,} } } } {\rm\text{ in this step we used series expansion of dilogarithm}}\\
{\rm\text{Now recall Walli's integral}} \Rightarrow \displaystyle J = \frac{\pi }{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^2}}}.} \frac{{C_{2n}^n}}{{{4^n}}},{\rm\text{ utilise the ordinary generating function for the central binomial coefficients}}\\
\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{x^n}C_{2n}^n}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - 4x} }} \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{x^n}C_{2n}^n}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - 4x} }} - 1 \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{x^{n - 1}}C_{2n}^n}  = \frac{1}{x}\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - 4x} }} - 1} \right) \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^n}}}{n}C_{2n}^n}  = 2\ln \left( 2 \right) - 2\ln \left( {1 + \sqrt {1 - 4x} } \right)\\
 \displaystyle\Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{n - 1}}}}{n}C_{2n}^n}  = \frac{1}{x}\left( {2\ln \left( 2 \right) - 2\ln \left( {1 + \sqrt {1 - 4x} } \right)} \right) \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{{n^2}}}C_{2n}^n}  = 3{\ln ^2}\left( 2 \right) - {\ln ^2}\left( {1 + \sqrt {1 - 4x} } \right) - 2\ln \left( 2 \right)\ln \left( {1 - \sqrt {1 - 4x} } \right) + 2\ln \left( 2 \right)\ln \left( x \right) + 2{\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_2}\left( {\frac{1}{2}\left( {1 - \sqrt {1 - 4x} } \right)} \right)\\
 \displaystyle\Rightarrow J = \frac{\pi }{2}{\left. {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{{n^2}}}C_{2n}^n} } \right|_{x = \frac{1}{4}}} = \frac{\pi }{2}\left( {\frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{6} - 2{{\ln }^2}\left( 2 \right)} \right) = \frac{{{\pi ^3}}}{{12}} - \pi {\ln ^2}\left( 2 \right)\\
 * \displaystyle K = \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {{{\ln }^2}\left( {\sin \left( x \right)} \right)dx}  = \frac{1}{8}.{\left. {\frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{a^2}}}} \right|_{a = b = \frac{1}{2}}}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {2{{\sin }^{2a - 1}}\left( x \right){{\cos }^{2b - 1}}\left( x \right)dx} {\rm\text{. Now, recall the trigonometric form of the Beta function}}:{\rm B}\left( {a,b} \right) = \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {2{{\sin }^{2a - 1}}\left( x \right){{\cos }^{2b - 1}}\left( x \right)dx} \\
 \displaystyle\Rightarrow K = \frac{1}{8}.{\left. {\frac{{{d^2}}}{{d{a^2}}}} \right|_{a = b = \frac{1}{2}}}{\rm B}\left( {a,b} \right) = {\left. {\frac{1}{8}\left( {\left( {{{\left( {{\psi ^{(0)}}\left( a \right) - {\psi ^{(0)}}\left( {a + b} \right)} \right)}^2} - {\psi ^{(1)}}\left( {a + b} \right) + {\psi ^{(1)}}\left( a \right)} \right){\rm B}\left( {a,b} \right)} \right)} \right|_{a = b = \frac{1}{2}}} = \frac{1}{8}\left( {\left( {{{\left( {{\psi ^{(0)}}\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right) - {\psi ^{(0)}}\left( 1 \right)} \right)}^2} - {\psi ^{(1)}}\left( 1 \right) + {\psi ^{(1)}}\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)} \right){\rm B}\left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}} \right)} \right)\\
{\rm\text{Using particular values}}:{\psi ^{(0)}}\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right) =  - \gamma  - 2\ln \left( 2 \right),{\psi ^{(0)}}\left( 1 \right) =  - \gamma ,{\psi ^{(1)}}\left( 1 \right) = \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{6},{\psi ^{(1)}}\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right) = \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{2}\\
\displaystyle {\rm{And}}:{\rm B}\left( {\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}} \right) = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}} = \pi  \Rightarrow K = \frac{1}{8}\pi \left( {4{{\ln }^2}\left( 2 \right) + \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{3}} \right) = \frac{{{\pi ^3}}}{{24}} + \frac{\pi }{2}{\ln ^2}\left( 2 \right)\\
 * \displaystyle {\rm\text{Adding all results}}:\displaystyle I =  - \frac{1}{8}J - \frac{1}{4}K =  - \frac{1}{8}\left( {\frac{{{\pi ^3}}}{{12}} - \pi {{\ln }^2}\left( 2 \right)} \right) - \frac{1}{4}\left( {\frac{{{\pi ^3}}}{{24}} + \frac{\pi }{2}{{\ln }^2}\left( 2 \right)} \right) =  - \frac{{{\pi ^3}}}{{48}},{\rm\text{ hence proved}}{\rm{.}}
\end{array}$$