# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{t \ln (1-\sin{t})}{\sin t} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

In a problem in scattering theory, this integral arises:
$$\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \frac{t \ln (1-\sin{t})}{\sin t} dt}$$  I have tried a number of approaches to evaluating the integral, which I suspect has a closed form solution. The reason is that I generated a numerical value for the integral, $-3.87578458503\ldots$ and after a bit of numerical exploration I found this to agree with $-\pi^3/8$.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried Wolfram Alpha? Do you have any reason from physics to suspect a power of $\pi$? Are there related scattering theory problems that lead to similar integrals? Doe the appearance of $\pi$ matter, or is all you need the numerical value?

Comment: You may get some inspirations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164183/how-to-evaluate-i-int-limits-0-pi-2-fracx-log-sinx-sinx-dx)

Comment: Any chance you can (briefly) describe or reference the problem in scattering theory that leads to this integral? Just curious to see it arise in context.

Answer (score 10):

First set $\sin t=u$ then $u=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ and use the fact that $\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)=\tan^{-1}(x)$ we get

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{t\ln(1-\sin t)}{\sin t}dt=\int_0^1\frac{\sin^{-1}(u)\ln(1-u)}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}du\\=-2\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\right)dx=-2\left(\frac{\pi^3}{16}\right)=-\frac{\pi^3}{8}$$

where the last integral is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3204668)