# how to integrate $\;I(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-a^2x^2)}{ x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to solve this integral?

$$I(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-a^2x^2)}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

There was a mistake in the original - I forgot a factor in the expansion of the log.  My apologies.

Expand the log in a Taylor series (assuming $|a| \lt 1$):

$$I(a) = -\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2 k+2}}{k+1} \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^{2 k}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = -\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac1{2^{2 k}}\binom{2 k}{k} \frac{a^{2 (k+1)}}{k+1}$$

(The derivation of the integral may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556280/prove-int-01-fracx2-2-x2-ln1xx3-sqrt1-x2-mathrm-dx-frac-pi/556391#556391).)

The derivative of the sum is a well-known Taylor expansion in its own right.  Thus,

$$I'(a) = -\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2 a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} $$

$$I(a) = 0 \implies I(a) = -\pi \left (1-\sqrt{1-a^2} \right ) $$

Comment: Consider the Taylor series for the function $(1-a^2)^{-1/2}$: $$1+\frac1{1!}(-1/2)(-a^2)+\frac1{2!} (-1/2) (-3/2) (-a^2)^2 + \frac1{3!} (-1/2)(-3/2)(-5/2) (-a^2)^3 + \cdots$$ I hope you see a pattern emerge.  Manipulate it to get the form I have in the sum for $I'(a)$.

Comment: That was very helpful, I never used binomial sums for integrals. Thanks for a experience. ;)

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{#c00000}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\,{\rm I}\pars{a}&\ =\
\overbrace{\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - a^{2}x^{2}} \over x^{2}\root{1 - x^{2}}}}
\,\dd x}^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{x\ \equiv\ \cos\pars{\theta}}}}\ =\
\int_{\pi/2}^{0}{\ln\pars{1 - a^{2}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}} \over \cos^{2}\pars{\theta}\root{1 - \cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}}
\,\bracks{-\sin\pars{\theta}\dd\theta}
\\[5mm]&=\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\ln\pars{1 - {a^{2} \over \tan^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1}}\sec^{2}\pars{\theta}
\,\dd\theta}^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\tan\pars{\theta}\ \equiv t}}}\ =\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{1 - {a^{2} \over t^{2} + 1}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\ln\pars{t^{2} + 1 - {a^{2}}} - \ln\pars{t^{2} + 1}}\,\dd t
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{{t^{2} \over t^{2} + 1} - {t^{2} \over t^{2} + 1 - a^{2}}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{-\,{1 \over t^{2} + 1} + {1 - a^{2} \over t^{2} + 1 - a^{2}}}\,\dd t
=-2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}
+2\root{1 - a^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}
\\[5mm]&=-2\pars{1 - \root{1 - a^{2}}}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}}
_{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\pi \over 2}}}\ =\
\color{#66f}{\large -\pi\pars{1 - \root{1 - a^{2}}}}
\end{align}

Comment: The integration by parts needs a bit explanation specially in the $uv$ term when substituting $x\to\infty$.  L'Hôpital's rule is needed there. Overall, this is a nice answer (+1)

Comment: @Venus The integration by parts involve two limits which  clearly vanish out:
$$
\lim_{t\ \to\ \infty}\left[\,
t\ln\left(\, 1 - {a^{2} \over t^{2} + 1}\,\right)\,\right] = 0\,,
\qquad
\lim_{t\ \to\ 0}\left[\,
t\ln\left(\, 1 - {a^{2} \over t^{2} + 1}\,\right)\,\right] = 0
$$

Comment: So obvious solution, very nice. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Alternately, try differentiating under the integral sign with regard to *a*.