# Definite Integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x^2-x+1)}{x^2-x}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x^2-x+1)}{x^2-x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

WA gives $\pi^2/9$

Comment: Use the fact that $\dfrac1{x^2-x}=\dfrac1{x(x-1)}=\dfrac1{x-1}-\dfrac1x$ to break it up into two convergent integrals. Then notice that $x^2-x+1=\dfrac{x^3+1}{x+1}$ , and use the fact that $\ln\dfrac ab=\ln a-\ln b$. Then employ the well-known Taylor series for the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mhenni has struck first with the approach I have taken, but I would like to elaborate.  Again, the integrand may be Taylor expanded:

$$\begin{align}-\int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{[1-(x-x^2)]}}{x-x^2}  &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n+1} \int_0^1 dx \, x^n (1-x)^n\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{n+1} \frac{n!^2}{(2 n+1)!}\\ &=2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(2 n+2) (2 n+1) \binom{2 n}{n}} \end{align}$$

[It turns out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420732/trying-to-prove-that-sum-j-2-infty-prod-k-1j-frac2-kjk-1-pi/420886#420886) that

$$\frac{\arcsin{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2 n} x^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1) \binom{2 n}{n}} $$

So the sum in question is simply

$$4 \int_0^1 dx \frac{\arcsin{(x/2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2/4}} = 8 \int_0^{\pi/6} d\theta \, \theta = \frac{\pi^2}{9}$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: While you have every right to downvote this answer, as well as Mhenni's, it would be nice to know how either of these answers constitutes something not useful.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x^{2} - x}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> Roots of $\ds{x^{2} - x + 1 = 0}$ are given by
>   $\ds{\quad x_{\rm r} \equiv {1 + \root{3}\ic \over 2}\quad}$ and
>   $\ds{\quad{1 \over x_{\rm r}} = x_{\rm r}^{*}}$.

\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x^{2} - x}\,\dd x}
=-\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1}\pars{{1 \over x} + {1 \over 1 - x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x}\,\dd x
=-2\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x/x_{\rm r}} \over x}\,\dd x+
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x/x_{\rm r}^{*}} \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=-2\bracks{\int_{0}^{1/x_{\rm r}}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x+
\int_{0}^{1/x_{\rm r}*}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x}
=2\bracks{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over x_{\rm r}} +
{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{x_{\rm r}}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{z}}$ is the [Dilogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#CITEREFSchr.C3.B6dinger1952).

Note that $\ds{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{z} = -\ln\pars{1 - z}}$ and
$\ds{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{z} = \int_{0}^{z}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t}$.

> By using the [Dilogarithm Inversion Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#CITEREFSchr.C3.B6dinger1952)
>   $\ds{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{z} + {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over z}
>      =-\,{\pi^{2} \over 6} - \half\,\ln^{2}\pars{-z}}$ where $\ds{z \not\in \left[\vphantom{\Large A}0, 1\right)}$:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x^{2} - x}\,\dd x}
> =2\bracks{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 6} - \half\,\ln^{2}\pars{-1 - \root{3}\ic \over 2}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\bracks{-\,{\pi^{2} \over 6} - \half\,\pars{-\,{2\pi \over 3}}^{2}}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x^{2} - x + 1} \over x^{2} - x}\,\dd x = {\pi^{2} \over 9}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach which is based on the Taylor series and the beta function

$$ I = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x^2-x)^k}{(x^2-x)}dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k} \int_{0}^{1}{x^{k-1}(1-x)^{k-1}}dx $$

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k} \beta(k,k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k} \frac{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(2k)} = 4(\sin^{-1}(1/2))^2 \sim 1.096622711. $$

Comment: How do you go from  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k} \frac{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(2k)}$ to $4(\sin^{-1}(1/2))^2 $?

Answer (score 1):

Let me present you the simplest approach I could even think about. At start, I have to say I am using a method suggested earlier in comments by @Lucian . So it begins by computation of this kind of integrals, by expanding the integral in power series :

$$I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^n)}{x} \;\mathrm{d}x= -\int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{nk-1}}{k} \;\mathrm{d}x = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nk^2}=-\frac{\zeta{(2)}}{n} $$

Next, using the fact that,

$$\frac{1}{x^2-x}=-\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{x}$$

And $x^2-x+1$ is symmetric inder transformation $x \to 1-x$ we get for our original integral :

$$I=-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(x^2-x+1\right)}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x=-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x^3}\cdot\frac{1-x}{1-x^2}\right)}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x = -2\left(I_6-I_3-I_2+I_1\right)=2\zeta(2)\left(\frac16-\frac13-\frac12+1\right)=\frac23\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{9}$$